# Running a VR application on a remote computer with PsExec

Tags: virtual-reality, unreal-engine4, psexec

I'm using PSTools to run a VR application, developed in Unreal and using and Oculus Rift S headset. I am able to launch the app remotely but it's ignoring the VR headset. It just executes normally without VR, it doesn't render or take any input from the headset.  The command looks like this:

```
.\PsExec.exe -i -d \\IP "path\NetworkTest.exe"
```

On the other hand, if I launch the .exe locally from my target PC, VR features work perfectly.

Am I missing something? May some execution argument? Has anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's useful to someone at some point. OVRPlugin was crashing at initialization and I was able to solve it by adding a user and password to the commmand, so it looks like:

```
.\PsExec.exe -i -d -u "DOMAIN\username" -p "password" \\192.168.0.100  "path\NetworkTest.exe"
```